# Unused indexes in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have the following code snippet to list unused indexes in Mongo but how can I exclude TTL indexes from the results?

```
db.getMongo().getDBNames().forEach(function (dbname) {
    if (dbname != "admin") {
    db.getSiblingDB(dbname).getCollectionNames().forEach(function (cname) {
        output = db.getSiblingDB(dbname)[cname].aggregate({$indexStats:{} });  
        output.forEach(function(findUnused) { 
        if (findUnused.accesses.ops == 0 && findUnused.name != "_id_") {  
            print(dbname + " \t" + cname + " \t" + JSON.stringify(findUnused) );  
        } 
        })
    })
}})
```

Typical outoput is below am not sure how to exclude the TTL indexes denoted by the expireAfterSeconds field.

```
dbname  collection {"name":"collection","key":{"backupTime":1},"host":"server:27017","accesses":{"ops":0,"since":"2001-01-12T10:01:03.338Z"},"spec":{"v":2,"key":{"backupTime":1},"name":"collection","expireAfterSeconds":1234567}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your aggregation, after the `$indexStats` stage, you can add a `$match` with `"spec.expireAfterSeconds": {$exists: false}` to check for TTL indexs. That is a field unique to TTL indexs.

```js
db.orders.aggregate([
  {
    $indexStats: {}
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "spec.expireAfterSeconds": {
        $exists: false
      },
      "accesses.ops": 0,
      "name": {
        $ne: "_id_"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8nPdEqMjNoq)

Comment: That's ace, thanks a lot. I also added an additional parsing condition on the spec which also does the same thing

 ``` { if (findUnused.accesses.ops == 0 && findUnused.name != "_id_" && !findUnused.spec.expireAfterSeconds) ```
 
It works on some but not on others and where it does not work throws an error below\

```  "message" : "$indexStats is only valid as the first stage in a pipeline." ```

If i'm reading the pipeline right then indexstats must be executed first to get the info before parsing the JSON fields from the first output.

Comment: @ribbit you can just put the 2 criteria inside the `$match`. Updated the answer to reflect that. As a warm reminder, you should leverage db filtering if possible instead of performing the filtering in application level(i.e. js level for your case) as it would be more performant

Comment: very true in regards to using db filtering rather having the app do that for you. Thanks for your help!